# How to change expose settings for a specific space on osx

Tags: macos, mac, osx-spaces, expose

Is there a way to change expose settings for a specific space?

reason:
sometimes I run windows in another space full screen. I don't like things happening when I put my cursor in the corner. Especially if I'm playing a game.

I was thinking I could find a hotkey utility to turn off expose, but I'd rather it be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.mactipper.com/2008/04/lava-corners-turn-on-and-off-hot.html) an applescript for turning on and off hot corners. You can bind a trigger to it in [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) - eg. a mouse gesture or a hotkey.

Cheers!